# How do I fill an area with rectangles?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, arcgis-10.1

So I have a grid of rectangles and I need them to fill a certain area. How do I make those rectangular polygons to follow the borders of that area, and fill it up? Basically I would like to get a result as seen in the picture[image]

Comment: Try this tool: https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#qgiscreategrid

Comment: I am using ArcGIS

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/how-create-fishnet-works.htm

Are you creating an analysis for solar panels?

Comment: ArcGIS analogue: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-fishnet.htm

Comment: What version of ArcMap are you using? tagging be release isn't done any more and 10.1 is too ancient to consider being the same product.

Comment: Yes, doing solar panels. I managed to put on a grid, but how do I create the gaps between each rectangular? They all stuck together, I need to separate them

Comment: To "separate" them it visually looks like you could just delete every other line of a grid.